# Properly implement Custom Adapter to show images with Picasso

Tags: android, adapter, picasso

I have been writing and rewriting this adapter many times in different ways, but only thing I get is a blank screen when I launch the app.

I want to load images into a gridview using picasso and a string of urls as base data, but I'm not really going forward with it.

https://github.com/Valakias/PortFolioMovieApp

Comment: You could have a look in this [example](https://github.com/natangr/CheesecakeChallenge/tree/natan/app/src/main/java/com/example/naan/cheesecakechallenge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the imageView width is 0 (check it using: `Poster.getWidth();`), that's why you're not seeing the images, the Custom Adapter is fine.

You can fix this, using `setLayoutParams` to set a width/height to the `imageView` as the example below:

```
if (convertView == null) {
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);

   //Get screen size, and divide it by the number of columns of your grid view.
   int width = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / 2;
   ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_item_image)).setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(width, width));
}

ImageView Poster = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_item_image);
Picasso.with(getContext())
       .load(getItem(position))
       .fit()
       .centerCrop()
       .into(Poster);
```

Or a different approach using `Picasso.resize`

```
//Get screen size, and divide it by the number of columns of your grid view.
int width = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / 2;
ImageView Poster = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_item_image);

Picasso.with(getContext())
    .load(getItem(position))     
    .resize(width, width)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(Poster);
```

Instead of `.centerCrop()` you can use `.centerInside()`

- **Using** `.centerCrop()`

[image]

- **Using** `'.centerInside()'` (This will respect image aspect ratio).

[image]

Comment: Yes, that was it! I thought that by setting the size of the imageview to Match_parent it would let the gridview decide the size, seems i was wrong. Thank you a lot sir, i was stuck on this, and no tutorial was actually explaining this, so i was really lost.

Comment: Something strange happens to the size of the imageview when inside a gridView/listView (I still don't know why it doesn't behave like in any other view), But I'm happy it worked for you, just out of curiosity, which of the two options were you looking for, centerInside or centerCrop?

Comment: Strange indeed! So strange sources out there should actually mention this :/ Im currently following the Udacity Nanodegree course, so eventually i'll have to display a list of poster movies, so i'll choose the stile that looks better i guess. I really need to read more documentation about these classes before i work on them, would spare me and others a few headaches.